# Groovy How to find key value in list of maps

Tags: arrays, groovy, associative-array, jenkins-groovy

I want to find a better solution than iterating through a list of maps, which looks like this:

```
[[name:"Gromit", likes:"cheese", id:1234],[name:"john", likes:"fries", id:1234],...]
```

I have a list of names like ["lisa","carl","bob"...]. so I want to search the list of maps for the 'likes' and 'id' associated with my names list, but I don't want to iterate through the list for every single name using some boolean code.

For a regular map, I think I can do this:

```
if(regularMap.containsKey(key)) {
    println regularmap[key]
}
```

How can I do something similar for a list of maps within a Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what form you want the results in but the following is a starting point:

```
    def inputData = [[name: "Gromit", likes: "cheese", id: 1234], [name: "john", likes: "fries", id: 1234]]
    def names = ["lisa", "Gromit", "carl", "bob", "john",]

    def results = []
    names.each { name ->
        def matchingMap = inputData.find { it.name == name }
        if (matchingMap) {
            results << [matchingMap.id, matchingMap.likes]
        }
    }
```

`results` will be `[[1234, cheese], [1234, fries]]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
listOfMaps.findAll{ it.name in names }
```